# PhP FileMaker API Related Records

Tags: php, filemaker

I need help to get related fields in my PHP application from filemaker Db.

in my filemaker I have 3 tables

> Category:
>    - ID
>    - Name
>    - Description
>
> SubCategory
>    - ID
>    - Category_ID
>    - Name
>    - Description
>
> Product
>    - ID
>    - SubCategory_ID
>    - Name

I need in my php get a hash with

```
 - Category1:
   -ID
   -Name
   -SubCategory_ID:
      -SubCategory:Name
      -Product_ID:
         -Product:Name
 - Category2:
 - CategoryN:
```

some one can please help me with the API of PHP filemaker to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

The FileMaker API for PHP is layout based, ie. you can only access fields that are present on the layout you are querying.
So you need a portal on the layout you are using, showing the related records you need. Any related records will then be included in the record object you receive.
The syntax to get the related records is something like this:

```
$relatedRecordsArray = $currentRecord->getRelatedSet('SubCategory');
```

I advice you to use a reserved layout for the PHP API with only the fields and portals you need for your PHP script. This is for performance reasons.

Also, there are many options available, I suggest you read up on the API in the FileMaker guide for custom web publishing.